# quelle.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script; gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'

Tags: haskell, terminal, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a Haskell program which takes a string from a txt file and adds it at the end of another string, in a different txt. file. But when I try to compile it in my terminal I get following error message:

```
C:\Users\Benni>ghc-9.2.3.exe vonquellezumziel1.hs quelle.txt ziel.txt
Loaded package environment from   C:\Users\Benni\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-9.2.3\environments\default  
Linking vonquellezumziel1.exe ...  
C://tools//ghc-9.2.3//mingw//bin/ld.exe:quelle.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script  
C://tools//ghc-9.2.3//mingw//bin/ld.exe:quelle.txt:0: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

that's the Haskell code which I got from my Prof.:

```
−− vonquellezumziel1.hs
importSystem.IO
main :: IO()
main = do 
leseGriff <- openFile "quelle.txt" ReadMode
inhalt <- hGetContents leseGriff
schreibGriff <- openFile "ziel.txt" AppendMode
hPutStr schreibGriff inhalt
hClose leseGriff
hClose schreibGriff
```

the variables are named in German so I hope that's not a problem.

the way I'm using to compile the programs is by using: ghc-9.2.3.exe filename

all the answers I found were for C or C++, but I'm using Haskell so I don't really know what to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should not add your input files to the compilation; just `ghc-9.2.3.exe vonquellezumziel1.hs`, no ".txt" files.

Comment: i tried that first but then the Programm does´nt work because it just prints a new line without the supposed string

Comment: Not including those files is not the reason for your program's undesirable behaviour. Your program works fine for me after fixing the typos (i.e. it appends the contents of "quelle.txt" to "ziel.txt"), so you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: i just realized that the Programm adds (appends) the string directly in the ziel.txt file. i thought it would combine the strings and print it in the terminal. Sorry my bad seems like there wasn't a problem to beginn with, i just didn't understand how it worked. But thank u very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing compilation and execution of the compiled program. When you run

```bash
> ghc-9.2.3.exe vonquellezumziel1.hs quelle.txt ziel.txt
```

you are telling the compiler to take the three files `vonquellezumziel1.hs`, `quelle.txt` and `ziel.txt`, and treat them as haskell files, and compile them to a binary executable.

What you actually want to do is first compile the program

```bash
> ghc-9.2.3.exe vonquellezumziel1.hs
```

Then run it

```bash
> ./vonquellezumziel1
```

The program does not take any command line arguments, it just reads and write files from disk in the current directory.

The code you pasted here looks like the formatting is broken, I believe the file should actually look like:

```hs
import System.IO

main :: IO()
main = do 
    leseGriff <- openFile "quelle.txt" ReadMode
    inhalt <- hGetContents leseGriff
    schreibGriff <- openFile "ziel.txt" AppendMode
    hPutStr schreibGriff inhalt
    hClose leseGriff
    hClose schreibGriff
```